# Selenium IDE PopUp in a PopUp (nested popups)

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am having difficulties with multiple popup operations. Sometimes nested popups created. I can do operation in first popup but I can't do anything when another nested popup created.

```
selenium.click("css=tfoot > tr > td > input[type=\"button\"]");
selenium.waitForPopUp("", "30000");
selenium.selectWindow("title=DEV.WORKCUBE.COM");
selenium.click("css=img[title=\" Kaynak Rezerve Edin  !\"]");
selenium.waitForPopUp("", "30000");
selenium.selectWindow("title=DEV.WORKCUBE.COM");
selenium.type("id=startdate", "21/08/2014");
```

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere?
Might want to check out: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_handle_pop_up_windows?

Comment: Might be because you selectWindow 2x on _"title=DEV.WORKCUBE.COM"_ it might catch the first one again. Not sure I have nothing to try it out on ;/
This might be of interrest: http://www.tonyzampogna.com/2012/01/28/selecting-popup-windows-in-selenium/
Try to selectWindow _null_  to select the current window see if that works

Comment: from a tester perspective, it's not good to have too many popups which deliver only a piece of information. We should convince dev team to make design change to get everything in side a single popup (if it's possible) OR 2nd popup only displays after 1st one disappears.

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang true same here =), 
User3556491, Try selecting a name or id for the 2e popup. Selecting the same title again will make you select the first popup again. Try changing that. Or give us an example somewhere of a nested popup so we can try it out

Comment: Thanks friends. My Company developers use Window open(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) . These popups dont have id or name attributes. They only have title attribute. I tried selectWindow null but it doesnt make sense. I will send you an example my company demo site. Site url: http://demo.workcube.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=agenda.form_upd_event&event_id=1831 2: Username: gokhan , Password: 1 , you will click Physical Asset Reservation button. You can try test case. Thanks again